# Getting internet connection through eth0 and wlan0 simultaneously

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, network-manager

I have disabled network manager on Ubuntu 12.04.

I need to do manual configuration:

1) Connect to Internet through eth0

> SUCCEEDED by using

```
 ifconfig eth0 up
 dhclient eth0
```

----> I am able to get Internet on my laptop.

2) Connected to a dummy hotspot through wlan0

SUCCEEDED by using wpa_supplicant & rsn encryption

After doing step 2, even-though both interfaces remain connected I loose Internet connection. Any help?

Though this is not my final required configuration, it will help me reach there.

Comment: Check your routing...

Comment: Could you give me some links to understand routing properly

Comment: Of course, sorry... Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64532/understanding-my-route-table