# Two NICs - How redirect traffic to specific NIC

Tags: networking

I need help to setup two NICs from my laptop.
I want to have all inbound/outbound traffic from/to the network 192.168.1.0 (Local Network) to be sent to the eth0 (Wired) and I want to have all other traffic to be sent to 192.168.2.0 (Wifi).

I have Ubuntu 18.04.

Let me know what additional information I should provide.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Is your laptop acting as the router that passes data between the two networks?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment.
No, I hava a router where my Windows and my Ubuntu are connect to and sharing the same network (192.168.2.0)

Comment: Try editing your [routing table](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64532/understanding-my-route-table). Be sure you understand how to restore it - it's very easy to break your network.